# Where session transactions are useful?

Tags: java, jms

I tried to understand the JMS API using [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnceh.html). While session object creation time we are passing 2 arguments to `createSession(argument1,argument2)`.

argument1 value is a `boolean` value.

If you specify,

`true` : it's a transacted session.

`false`: it's a non-transacted session.

My question was, What is difference between *transacted* and *non-transacted* sessions.For this I read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncgh/index.html). I understand better. But I am curious to know, where these 2 types of sessions are useful in real cases.

Can you explain with a simple example?

Answer (score 1):

A transacted session is useful, if you have to receive more than one message, before a logical transaction is complete.

For example, you have to consume three messages, before you are able to persist the result into a database. In this case, after you have completed the update into the database, you commit on the queue session to acknowledge three messages in one turn.

Otherwise, if your program is terminated after you have read two messages, these two messages are lost (if you use `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE`).

So the difference between transacted and non-transacted is the object you **acknowledge** on: In the first case, it's the session, and the other one it's the individual message.

Answer (score 0):

A transacted session allows you to do multiple things and for them to either all happen together, or not happen. A typical example might be you receive one message and send another one. JMS is considered a reliable transport, so assume that you want to ensure that the 2nd message is sent. If you do these things non-transacted and your processing application fails after the receive and before the send then you have lost information. To solve this problem you would make use of a transacted session. This would allow you to receive one message, send a second and then call Session.commit to make both occur at once.